# Find a close formula using generating functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I want to find the sum:
$$\sum \limits_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}2^{k-n}$$

I did it by using the binomial theorem and I got

$$\sum \limits_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}2^{k-n}
= 2^{-n} \sum \limits_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}2^k
= \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n3^n$$

I would like to know how to do it using generating functions. I have tried some calculations but I am stuck. This is what I have so far.

$$\sum \limits_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}2^{k-n}
=\sum \limits_{n\ge0} \sum \limits_{k\ge0} {n \choose k} 2^{k-n} x^n
=\sum \limits_{k\ge0} 2^k \sum \limits_{n\ge0} {n \choose k}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^n$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Another look at the problem**, using the fact that
$${\displaystyle {\binom {n}{k}}={\binom {n-1}{k-1}}+{\binom {n-1}{k}}}$$
we can construct the recurrence relation for the sequence:
$$a_n=\sum \limits_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}2^{k-n}=
{n\choose 0}2^{-n}+\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n-1} {n\choose k}2^{k-n}+{n\choose n}2^{0}=\\
{n\choose 0}2^{-n}+\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n-1} \left({n-1\choose k-1}+{n-1\choose k}\right)2^{k-n}+{n\choose n}2^{0}=\\
{n\choose 0}2^{-n}+\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n-1} {n-1\choose k-1}2^{(k-1)-(n-1)}+\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n-1}{n-1\choose k}2^{k-n}+\color{red}{{n\choose n}2^{0}}=\\
\color{blue}{{n\choose 0}2^{-n}}+\sum \limits_{k=0}^{n-2} {n-1\choose k}2^{k-(n-1)}+\color{red}{{n-1\choose n-1}2^{0}}+\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n-1}{n-1\choose k}2^{k-n}=\\
a_{n-1}+\color{blue}{\frac{1}{2}{n-1\choose 0}2^{-(n-1)}}+\frac{1}{2}\sum \limits_{k=1}^{n-1}{n-1\choose k}2^{k-(n-1)}=\\
a_{n-1}+\frac{1}{2}a_{n-1}=\frac{3}{2}a_{n-1}$$
This recurrence can be solved by induction, using generating functions or [characteristic polynomials](http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Characteristic_polynomial).

With generating functions, given $a_0=1$
$$f(x)=a_0+\sum\limits_{n=1}a_nx^n=1+\frac{3}{2}x\sum\limits_{n=1}a_{n-1}x^{n-1}=\\
1+\frac{3}{2}x\sum\limits_{n=0}a_{n}x^{n}=
1+\frac{3}{2}xf(x)$$
leading to
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{1-\frac{3}{2}x}=\sum\limits_{n=0}\color{red}{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n}x^n$$

Answer (score 4):

The binomial coefficient in $\sum \limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}2^{k-n}$ indicates that we could use the Cauchy-product of *exponential* generating functions. We have
\begin{align*}
A(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\frac{x^k}{k!},\ \ B(x)=\sum_{l=0}^\infty b_l\frac{x^l}{l!}\quad\longleftrightarrow\quad
A(x)B(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}a_kb_{n-k}\right)\frac{x^n}{n!}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}2^{k-n}}\right)\frac{x^n}{n!}
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}1^k\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-k}\right)\frac{x^n}{n!}\\
> &=\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}\right)\left(\sum_{l=0}^\infty\frac{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^l}{l!}\right)\\
> &=e^xe^{\frac{x}{2}}\\
> &=e^{\frac{3}{2}x}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\color{blue}{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n}\frac{x^n}{n!}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

Besides the more common method above we  also have the possibility to use *ordinary* generating functions. We can apply a transformation known as *Euler transform* of a series
\begin{align*}
A(x)=\sum_{n=  0}^\infty a_nx^n\quad\longrightarrow\quad
\frac{1}{1-x}A\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)=\sum_{n= 0}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}a_k\right)x^n
\end{align*}
This transformation formula together with a proof can be found e.g.  in [Harmonic Number Identities Via Euler's transform](http://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL12/Boyadzhiev/boyadzhiev3.pdf) by K.N. Boyadzhiev (see Lemma 1).

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}2^{k-n}}\right)x^n
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}2^k\right)\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^n\\
> &=\frac{1}{1-\frac{x}{2}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^n\left(\frac{\frac{x}{2}}{1-\frac{x}{2}}\right)^n\\
> &=\frac{1}{1-\frac{x}{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{1-2\left(\frac{\frac{x}{2}}{1-\frac{x}{2}}\right)}\\
> &=\frac{1}{1-\frac{3}{2}x}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\color{blue}{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n}x^n
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

Answer (score 3):

You have
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {\left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)2^{\,k - n} }  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {\left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)\left( {{1 \over 2}} \right)^{\,n - k} }  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {\left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)\left( {{1 \over 2}} \right)^{\,n - k} } 1^{\,k}  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {{1 \over 2} + 1} \right)^{\,n}  \cr} 
$$
or, if you prefer
$$
\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {\left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)z^{\,k - n} }  = z^{\, - n} \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n} {\left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)z^{\,k} }  = {{\left( {z + 1} \right)^{\,n} } \over {z^{\,n} }}
$$